# Как дать пользователю www-data доступ к запуску sh скрипта от имени root

Tags: php, root, sudo, raspbian

Raspbian OS
По сабжу:
Как дать пользователю **www-data** доступ к запуску `sh` скрипта от имени **root**?

Пробовал через `sudo visudo` добавлять строку:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/имя_скрипта.sh
```

Дополнительно: 
 1. Добавлял своего пользователя(pi) к группе www-data
 2. К папке съемных носителей добавлял разрешение `sudo chmod g+rwxs /media/pi`
 3. А также `sudo chgrp www-data /media/pi`

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт меняя директорию запуска через `chdir` (PHP) и запуском через `shell_exec`.

PHP скрипт должен удалять файлы с флешки. Не получается. 
Пытался заменить пользователя **www-data** на **pi**. Получилось, но это небезопасно. 
Поэтому вижу только путь через запуск без пароля от **root** скрипта пользователем **www-data**. 
 Прошу помощи.

Comment: вручную-то работает? `$ sudo -u www-data sudo /var/www/html/имя_скрипта.sh`. если да, то, возможно, вы с помощью функции `shell_exec()` выполняете не `sudo /var/www/html/имя_скрипта.sh`, а что-то совсем другое.

Comment: вручную спрашивает удалить ли файл? отвечаешь y . А он пишет - нет доступа.

Comment: значит, что-то явно неправильное вы пытаетесь сделать. приведите текст скрипта (нажав [edit])

Comment: вопрос такой - теоретически, имеет ли значение подключен ли это съемный носитель (флешка) или если бы необходимо было управлять файлами с домашнего каталога, то было бы проще? 
со скриптами уже сложнее. учитывая то, что 80 порт открыт во внутреннюю сеть, решил предоставить пользователю pi полномочия www-data.
Поэтому, это скорее вопрос на будущее.